# How can I load a specific private key into my wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core

Starting a **Private Node** using `bitcoin-qt`.

And then I generate a pair of keys for my own testing.

But unfortunately whenever I reset the node, it will generate a new pairs of keys, it makes my recursive test very tedious.

Is there a way for me to load a private key into my wallet instead of using `getnewaddress` every time and test with a new pair of keys?

Answer (score 1):

Replace wallet.dat with a saved copy

Comment: You mean replace the physical files inside the wallet directory?

Comment: @sk Yes. Make backups and restore backups, either manually or using the provided facilities. Practise first on non-valuable wallets until you are sure your actions have the effects you seek and no effects you consider harmful. On Ms-Windows see `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin\wallets\`